# Filtering subform using linkchildfield?

Tags: ms-access-2007

I need to filter a subform using a value in a combobox from the mainform.The value in the combobox is string(a sentence of a line or two)This value is called "Descr" in the select query of the subform and the name of combobox in the parent form is "cboOverdueDescr".
I have put the following code in the AfterUpdate event of the combobox.
LinkChildFields="Descr"
LinkMasterFields="cboOverdueDescr"
The problem is that the subform shows no record when I select any value in the combobox.However, the subform gets filtered accordingly when I do it the same way with another combobox which displays values like "B13-1000"

Comment: Have you put quotes - "" - on the link child and master fields? If you have, get rid of them.

Comment: Yes I have put double quotes and it has worked for a similar example but I do not know why not for this one.I just tried removing the double qoutes now and the error was "variable not found".

Comment: I read that wrong, I thought you had put quotes in the link property. You do need quotes for code.

Answer (score 0):

Even if your combo has a column called Descr, your form does not know that, all it knows is the number of columns, however, you can use a combobox as the link master field for a subform, the filter will use the value of the bound column. Just set the link master field to the name of the combo, there is no need to use an event.

Comment: I think I need to set the link master field to the name of the combo in the event because it is used for filtering the subform on the basis of the selected value.And how can I make the bound columnn concept work for me?

Comment: No you do not. Try it. Set the bound column to the number of the column that contains descr, counting from one.